# Webpack Module federation with react router - getting query params from microfrontend module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, webpack-module-federation

In my main app, I have a route with this path:

```
<Route path="/case/role/:caseNumber/:department" element={<RolePage />} />
```

`RolePage` imports microfrontend module with the same name, and looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

import PageTemplate from "./PageTemplate";

const moduleName = "rolePage";
const Role = React.lazy(() => import("role_case_ui/RolePage"));

export default function RolePage() {
    const { caseNumber, department } = useParams<{ caseNumber?: string; department?: string }>();
    const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const sessionState = searchParams.get("sessionState");

    return (
        <PageTemplate
            appName={"role_case_ui"}
            moduleName={moduleName}
            displayName={caseNumber ? "Edit roles" : "New case"}
        >
            <RolePage caseNumber={caseNumber} department={department} sessionState={sessionState} />
        </PageTemplate>
    );
}
```

Imported module looks like this:

```
export default function RolePage({ ...props }: IRolePageProps) {
    return (
        <RolePageProvider>
            <PageWrapper name="max-w-[1092px] mx-auto px-6 py-18 leading-xlarge tracking-wide">
                <RolebPageContainer {...props} />
            </PageWrapper>
        </RolePageProvider>
    );
}
```

I would like to access query params from that module that I importing if I go to an URL that looks for example like this:

```
/case/role/2300086/4807/?sessionState=23232
```

But, if I try to do that:

```
export default function RolePage({ ...props }: IRolePageProps) {
    const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const sessionState = searchParams.get("sessionState");
    return (
        <RolePageProvider>
            <PageWrapper name="max-w-[1092px] mx-auto px-6 py-18 leading-xlarge tracking-wide">
                <RolebPageContainer {...props} />
            </PageWrapper>
        </RolePageProvider>
    );
}
```

I get:

```
useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

It seems I can use router hooks only from the main app that imports module, but not from the imported module. Is there a way of getting this params directly from the module?

Comment: The route path params are part of the route definition, so OFC those are defined. Are there any queryString params to access from the URL? In other words, what is the URL you are trying to get a `sessionState` queryString parameter from? Can you [edit] to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: @DrewReese I have added an example of an url that I am trying to get search params from.

Comment: Your code appears to function as I'd expect it to here in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-query-param-undefined-yqmgsf?file=/src/App.tsx). Feel free to fork that sandbox and see if you can add more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue and share it back to us to inspect live.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DrewReese. I found out that the problem is actually with the webpack module federation that I am using in my project. I have updated the question with the issue.

Comment: Would instantiating your own [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object be sufficient for your use case?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your main app and the microfrontned have access to the *same*  react router instances.

This can be done by adding `react-router` as singleton to the `shared` section of your federation plugin configuration, like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      shared: {
        'react-router-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          version: '<your react-router-dom version>',
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

To be honest, I am not 100% sure if you really need `eager: true` and the `version` in the configuration. But this is the way I managed to get it working in my project.

See https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/#sharing-hints

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Christian. I tried it without `eager:true`, and it works as expected.